# iMacros: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)

Tags: imacros

> iMacros: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)

Что это значит, как и где это исправить, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: написано же, отсутствует точка с запятой где-то. зы: `im` обычно расшифровывают как `instant message` или _мгновенные сообщения_, так что если вы имели в виду несколько иное, то исправьте тэг к вопросу.

Comment: спасибо большое. Я просто впервые столкнулась с этой программой. Вот и пытаюсь понять, в чем моя ошибка )

Comment: все равно пишет это. я не пойму где это исправлять, я нажимаю на " воспроизвести " и пишет снова это . Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: вот это пишет SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)

Comment: вы хоть скиньте с чем работаете, я даже нагуглить по слову `iMaccros` (с двумя _c_) ничего не могу. это вообще что ? и приведите свой код, а не только сообщение о ошибке.

Comment: iMacros извините, одна лишняя, там есть версия для мазилы. я ее установила, забила туда что бы рассылалося по групам смс на стены, и в этоге нажимая на " воспроизвести " что бы началась рассылка, оно мне пишет такое

Comment: дак скопируйте в вопрос код, что вы туда "забили".

Comment: какой код ? я забивала туда слова предожения о работе ане код